# Track the value or event change of children prop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

So I have a component that I use in this way.

```
<SBCAInput>
  <input  defaultValue="" type="email" />
</SBCAInput>
```

And I implemented in the `SBCAInput` component like this.

```
import React , {useState} from 'react'

function SBCAInput(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    return (
        <div className={`sbca-input mb-3 ${ value==="" ? "" : "input-not-empty"}`}>
            <label>Email address</label>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}

export default SBCAInput
```

Now the challenge is I want to be able to **detect if the value of the `input` is empty** and change classes on the div container in the `SBCAInput` component.

**How do I track the value of the input component?**

Comment: IMO check `useRef` hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can access `value` using `children.props.value`**:

Parent component:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

function handleChange(e) {
  setEmail(e.target.value)
}

<SBCAInput>
  <input type="email" value={email} onChange={handleChange}/>
</SBCAInput>
```

SBCAInput component:

```
function SBCAInput({ children }) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`sbca-input mb-3 ${
        children.props.value ? 'input-not-empty' : ''
      }`}
    >
      <label>Email address</label>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: And if setting class conditionally becomes complex, you can use [classnames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66315964/2873538).

Comment: I see, do you think that can be able to use `useEffect` just to make sure, I get rid of the value prop in the `SBCAInput` component

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't seem to work, But I used this and it seems to work form me ` <div onChange={(e)=> setValue(e.target.value) } ..... >`