# how to hide div on click in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a div where I have `x` and I need to hide the whole div clicking on `x`. I use hook useState().

```
.noShow {
  display: none;
}    

  const [showed, setShowed] = useState(false)
  const hideNav = () => { 
      setShowed(true)
  } 
          <div className={ showed ? 'noShow' : ''} className='d-flex justify-content-between align-center pl-2 pr-2'>
             <h6>this is div</h6>
             <h6 onClick={hideNav}>x</h6>
          </div>
```

If I set showed - true initially it's hidden but when I click on `x` it does not work.

Comment: `onClick={hideNav}`, https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: With React you can hide things by just not rendering them.

Comment: You have mutiples `className` attributes. So, merge those, better by using [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package. `className={classnames("abc foo bar", {"noShow": !showed})}`

Comment: Similar: [Set active class conditionally in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66315964/2873538)

Answer (score 1):

Well you should call a function when you click hide.
Try like this.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [showed, setShowed] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div
      style={showed ? { display: "none" } : { display: "block" }}
      className="d-flex justify-content-between align-center pl-2 pr-2"
    >
      <h6>this is div</h6>
      <h6 onClick={(e) => setShowed(true)}>hide</h6>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can confirm here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-shadow-kz1mp?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to add function in braces in order to call the function onclick event

```js
function App(){
  const [showed, setShowed] = useState(false);
              
  return (
    <div style={{display: showed ? "none": ""}} className='d-flex justify-content-between align-center pl-2 pr-2'>
       <h6>this is div</h6>
       <h6 onClick={()=> setShowed(!showed)}>x</h6>
    </div>
  )
}
```