# Add & Remove class on button in React

Tags: reactjs, class, button

I am new in React so this question could sound a little bit but I couldnt figure it out. So I have two buttons and I want to add class on them when one of them are clicked. So buttons must be default className="button" and one of them clicked it should be added to the clicked button "selected-button" class. Besides, when the Button1 clicked, "selected-button" should be removed from Button2. I am really new in React sometimes, easy things could be confusing, thank you for your helps.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";

export class InstantQuote extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: false,
    };
  }

  toggleClass() {
    const currentState = this.state.active;
    this.setState({ active: !currentState });
  }

  render() {
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    };
    return (
      <Form className="instantquote shadow p-3 mb-5" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group controlId="formGroupFrom">
          <div className="selectable-buttons">
            <button type="submit"
            className={((this.state.active) ? "button button-selected": "button")}
            onClick={ () => this.setState({active: !this.state.active}) }>
              Button1
            </button>
            <button type="submit"
            className={((this.state.active) ? "button button-selected": "button")}
            onClick={ () => this.setState({active: !this.state.active}) }>
              Button2
            </button>
          </div>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

export default InstantQuote;
```

Comment: You can try classnames package. [Set active class conditionally in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66315964/2873538).

Comment: One problem with your code is that you don't add any space between the classes "button" and "button-selected", which means that when active is true, the className is "buttonbutton-selected"

Comment: I could fixed the clicked problem like this: <button type="submit"
            className={((this.state.active) ? "button button-selected": "button")}
            onClick={ () => this.setState({active: !this.state.active}) }>
              Button1
            </button> But still I dont know how I can remove the the class when it is clicked to another button

Comment: This npm package would be a great option if you encounter dynamic clas name assignment often in your code base => https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no method to identify which button is active, I would suggest having a unique identifier for each of the buttons and keep track of the active button in the component's state. Here is how the button can be declared.

```
this.state = {
  active: ""
}

...
<button
  id="button1"
  className={`button ${this.state.active === "button1" ? "button-selected" : ""}`}
  onClick={ () => this.setState({active: "button1"}) }>
   Button1
</button>
```

If your component needs a variable number of buttons, declare the information beforehand.

```
const buttons = [{label: "Button1", id: "button1"}, ...];
...
buttons.map(button => 
    <button
      id={button.id}
      className={`button ${this.state.active === button.id ? "button-selected" : ""}`}
      onClick={ () => this.setState({active: button.id}) }>
       {button.label}
    </button>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `active` state variable to `activeButton` that holds an identifier (the name for example) of the active button. If you click on an already active button, you set the `activeButton` to empty string.

```
    this.state = {
       activeButton: ""
    }

    const onButtonClick = (buttonName) => 
        setState({...this.state, 
                  activeButton: this.state.activeButtonn === buttonName 
                                ? "" 
                                : buttonName);
    
    render(){
       ...
       <button 
           type="submit"
           className={'button'+ this.state.activeButton === "Button1" && ' button-selected'}
           onClick={ () => onButtonClick("Button1") }>
              Button1
       </button>
       <button type="submit"
           className={'button'+ this.state.activeButton === "Button2" && ' button-selected'}
           onClick={ () => onButtonClick("Button2") }>
              Button2
       </button>
    ...
}
```